# Разбиение строк текста на слова Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Необходимо разбить строки текста на слова, но так, чтобы попутно исключить знаки препинания. Промежуточный код у меня выглядить вот так:

```
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np


f=open("sentences.txt","r")
f_lower=[]

for n in f:
f_lower.append(n.lower())


f_sep_words=[]
for n in f_lower:
m=n.split(' ')
for q in m:
    f_sep_words.append(q)


print (f_sep_words)
```

Результат примерно такой:

> ['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs,', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process.\n]

Как задать разделитель в строке `m=n.split(' ')` чтобы он делил строки не по пробелам, а по знакам препинания?
Также прошу подсказать, как удалять пустые слова?

Comment: пустые слова == пробелы или == "" ?

Comment: пробелы, или символы переноса строки "\n"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно через регулярку:

```
import re

text = 'in comparison to dogs, cats have not undergone major changes during the domestication process.'

words = re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b', text)
print(words)
```

Консоль:

```
['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process']
```

**PS.**

Из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> \b – граница слова
>
> \w – Буквенный или цифровой символ или знак
> подчёркивания

Comment: Спасибо!
Тогда дополнительный вопрос: как еще лучше почистить список исключив слова-артикли "a", "the"?

Comment: Например, через генератор: `ignore_words = ['a', 'the']` `words = [word for word in words if word not in ignore_words]`